# Guardar pedidos en base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

tengo un carrito y estoy trabajando en el boton de confirmar la compra. Los productos llegan al carrito por medio de un while, y guardo los datos que necesito de cada articulo en variables. El problema es que al hacer el submit solo me imprime los valores de mi último articulo (supongo que es porque se sobrescribe la variable) necesito que si mi carrito tiene 2 productos al momento de hacer submit, se me inserten 2 filas en base de datos.
Este es el while con el que muestro los productos seleccionados en carrito:

```html
$direct = "img/libros/";
                 $sql2 = "SELECT I.ISBN_id,I.titulo,I.imagen,I.precio,U.id,it.idOrdenes,it.libro,it.cantidad,it.usuario FROM lecturas_db.inventario I,lecturas_db.usuarios U,lecturas_db.items it WHERE U.id = it.usuario AND I.ISBN_id = it.libro AND it.usuario = $id";
     $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
                <form method="POST" class="Prod">
                <div>
                    <div class="imagenProd">
                        <img src="<?php echo $direct.$row['imagen'] ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tituloProd">
                        <center><b><?php echo $row['titulo'] ?></b></center>
                    </div><br><br>
                    <div class="cantidadProd">
                        <center><b><?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?></b> unidad/es</center>
                    </div><br><br>
                    <div class="subtotalProd">
                        <center>Subtotal: <b>$<?php $subtotal = $row['precio']*$row['cantidad'];
                        echo $subtotal;
                        $total += $subtotal;
                        ?></b></center> 
                    </div><br><br>
                    <div class="eliminarProd">
      <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row['libro'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="cantidadOrdenes" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="precio" value="<?php echo $row['precio'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes']?>">
                        <input type="submit" value="ELIMINAR" name="eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div><br><br>
                <?php if($_POST['eliminar']) {
      $id_eliminar = intval($_POST['id']);
                        $sql3 = "DELETE FROM lecturas_db.items WHERE idOrdenes = $id_eliminar LIMIT 1";
                        $res1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql3);
                        if($res1 > 0) {
                            echo "<script>
                            location.href='index.php';
                            </script>";
                        } else {
                            echo "nada";
                        } 
     } 
     $isbn = $row['libro'];
     $cantidadOrdenes = $row['cantidad'];
     $usuario = $row['usuario'];
     $precio = $row['precio']*$row['cantidad'];
     echo $isbn;
     echo $cantidadOrdenes;
     echo $usuario;
     echo $precio;
     ?>
            </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

```
            <form method="POST" class="Prod">
            <div>
                <div class="imagenProd">
                    <img src="<?php echo $direct.$row['imagen'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="tituloProd">
                    <center><b><?php echo $row['titulo'] ?></b></center>
                </div><br><br>
                <div class="cantidadProd">
                    <center><b><?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?></b> unidad/es</center>
                </div><br><br>
                <div class="subtotalProd">
                    <center>Subtotal: <b>$<?php $subtotal = $row['precio']*$row['cantidad'];
                    echo $subtotal;
                    $total += $subtotal;
                    ?></b></center> 
                </div><br><br>
                <div class="eliminarProd">
                    <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row['libro'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cantidadOrdenes" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="precio" value="<?php echo $row['precio'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes']?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="ELIMINAR" name="eliminar">
                </div>
            </div><br><br>
            <?php if($_POST['eliminar']) {
                    $id_eliminar = intval($_POST['id']);
                    $sql3 = "DELETE FROM lecturas_db.items WHERE idOrdenes = $id_eliminar LIMIT 1";
                    $res1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql3);
                    if($res1 > 0) {
                        echo "<script>
                        location.href='index.php';
                        </script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "nada";
                    } 
                } 
                $isbn = $row['libro'];
                $cantidadOrdenes = $row['cantidad'];
                $usuario = $row['usuario'];
                $precio = $row['precio']*$row['cantidad'];
                echo $isbn;
                echo $cantidadOrdenes;
                echo $usuario;
                echo $precio;
                ?>
        </form>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hola, podrías poner el código en donde detectas la sobreescritura de la variable y el While para que sea más fácil ayudarte?

Comment: Ahi te copie el codigo de mi while, las variables que creo que se reemplazan son las ultimas 4 (isbn,cantidadOrdenes,usuario y precio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La gestión de arrays en los formularios se realiza incluyendo corchetes [] en los nombre del elemento, algo así:

```
<?php  foreach($articulos as $articulo ) {?>
    <input name="id[]" value="<?=$articulo['id']?>" type="hidden">
    <input name="nombre[]" value="<?=$articulo['nombre']?>">
    <input name="precio[]" value="<?=$articulo['precio']?>">
    <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $articulo['id'] ?>" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
<?php } ?>
```

De esta manera te llegarán tres arrays: $_POST['id'], $_POST['nombre'] y $_POST['precio'] con tantos elementos como repeticiones tengas en el html.

Si se dejan los corchetes vacíos se generará un indice numérico automático, pero si se prefiere se le puede indicar un índice específico:

**PHP**

```
<?php  foreach($articulos as $articulo ) {?>
    <input name="nombre[<?=$articulo['id']?>]" value="<?=$articulo[$contador]['nombre']?>">
    <input name="precio[<?=$articulo['id']?>]" value="<?=$articulo[$contador]['precio']?>">
    <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $articulo['id'] ?>" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
<?php } ?>
```

**HTML**

```
    <input name="nombre[1025]" value="monitor">
    <input name="precio[1025]" value="150.25">
    <button type="submit" value="1025" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
    <input name="nombre[60]" value="teclado">
    <input name="precio[60]" value="15">
    <button type="submit" value="60" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
```

en este caso usaremos el `id` del elemento como indice del array de datos.

En tu caso quedaría algo así:

```
<div class="eliminarProd">
    <input type="hidden" name="isbn[]" value="<?php echo $row['libro'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cantidadOrdenes[]" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="usuario[]" value="<?php echo $row['usuario'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="precio[]" value="<?php echo $row['precio'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes'] ?>">
    <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes'] ?>" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
</div>
```

y para eliminar (o editar o lo que sea):

```
   <?php if($_POST['eliminar']) {
                $id_eliminar = intval($_POST['eliminar']);
                $sql3 = "DELETE FROM lecturas_db.items WHERE idOrdenes = $id_eliminar LIMIT 1";
                ....
    ?>
```

Si necesitas alguna aclaración adicional avisa.

(edito)

Tu código inicial tenía algunos errores que se me pasó comentar, te dejo la corrección que creo necesita:

```
<form method="POST" class="carrito">
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
        <div class="Prod">
            <div class="imagenProd">
                <img src="<?php echo $direct . $row['imagen'] ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="tituloProd">
                <center><b><?php echo $row['titulo'] ?></b></center>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="cantidadProd">
                <center><b><?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?></b> unidad/es</center>
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="subtotalProd">
                <center>Subtotal: <b>$<?php
                        $subtotal = $row['precio'] * $row['cantidad'];
                        echo $subtotal;
                        $total += $subtotal;
                        ?></b></center> 
            </div><br><br>           
            <div class="eliminarProd">
                <input type="hidden" name="isbn[]" value="<?php echo $row['libro'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="cantidadOrdenes[]" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="usuario[]" value="<?php echo $row['usuario'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="precio[]" value="<?php echo $row['precio'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes'] ?>">
                <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes'] ?>" name="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
            </div>                
        </div><br><br>
<?php } ?>
<button type="submit" name="pocesar">Procesar compra</button>
</form>
```

**IMPORTANTE:** solo hay un `<form>` así debe ser para que te lleguen todos los productos (en forma de array) y no solo el último. Y el bucle `while` esta dentro del formulario mostrando cada uno de los artículos.
Finalmente el botón de de compra queda fuera del bucle (solo saldrá uno) antes de cerrar el formulario.

Fíjate que eliminé la parte que procesa el borrado, pues lo tenías dentro del bucle y no debe ser así, el procesamiento se realiza una sola vez así que va fuera del bucle.

Acostumbrate a separar las partes de código que imprimen pantallas de las partes que procesan la información.

Así pues, la parte que procesaría el formulario queda con:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['eliminar']) {
    $id_eliminar = intval($_POST['eliminar']);
    $sql3 = "DELETE FROM lecturas_db.items WHERE idOrdenes = $id_eliminar LIMIT 1";
    // resto del codigo de eliminación....
}


if ($_POST['procesar']) {
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $indice => $id_producto) {

        $id = $id_producto;
        $cantidadOrdenes = $_POST['cantidadOrdenes'][$indice];
        $precio = $_POST['precio'][$indice];

        // resto del codigo de la compra (para cada articulo)....
    }

    // resto del codigo de la compra 
}

?>
```

Te llegará cada uno de os artículos en un array, que, en este caso, leemos de forma secuencial. 
Y ya así puedes ir guardando de uno en uno, o construir el SQL que guarde todos a la vez o lo que prefieras.

Un saludo.

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1</sup> 
<sub>`<?=$variable?>`  es una forma corta de poner `<?php echo $variable ?>`</sub>

Comment: El problema para eliminar los productos ya quedo solucionado, mi problema es que cuando hago click en el boton para confirmar la compra, mi base de datos solo me guarda el ultimo producto agregado al carrito. No se si el problema esta en las variables que se sobreescriben o es que no puedo guardar mas de una fila por query. No se si me explico

Comment: Te dejo una aclarción adicional