# Problema con boton Confirmar Compra de mi carrito

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Vuelvo a hacer una pregunta que ya hice pero de otra manera, a ver si así me explico mejor. Tengo hecho un carrito en constante comunicación con mi base de datos (Cuando el usuario selecciona un producto se inserta en una tabla "items", y es de esta tabla de donde muestro los productos del carrito por medio de un while). Ahora bien, con mi botón de Confirmar Compra lo que busco es que se me guarden los productos seleccionados en la tabla "Ordenes". El problema es que si tengo mas de un producto seleccionado solo se me guarda el ultimo agregado. Quiero saber como insertar varias filas en mi tabla con una sola sentencia sql, y como evitar sobrescribir mis variables. Les dejo código.
**WHILE que muestra productos seleccionados**

```html
<?php 
                 $direct = "img/libros/";
                 $sql2 = "SELECT I.ISBN_id,I.titulo,I.imagen,I.precio,U.id,it.idOrdenes,it.libro,it.cantidad,it.usuario FROM lecturas_db.inventario I,lecturas_db.usuarios U,lecturas_db.items it WHERE U.id = it.usuario AND I.ISBN_id = it.libro AND it.usuario = $id";
     $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
<form method="POST" class="Prod">
  <div>
    <div class="imagenProd">
      <img src="<?php echo $direct.$row['imagen'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="tituloProd">
      <center><b><?php echo $row['titulo'] ?></b></center>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="cantidadProd">
      <center><b><?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?></b> unidad/es</center>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="subtotalProd">
      <center>Subtotal: <b>$<?php $subtotal = $row['precio']*$row['cantidad'];
                        echo $subtotal;
                        $total += $subtotal;
                        ?></b></center>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="eliminarProd">
      <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row['libro'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="cantidadOrdenes" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="precio" value="<?php echo $row['precio'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['idOrdenes'] ?>">
      <input type="submit" value="ELIMINAR" name="eliminar">
    </div>
  </div><br><br>
  <?php  
      if($_POST['eliminar']) {
      $id_eliminar = intval($_POST['id']);
                        $sql3 = "DELETE FROM lecturas_db.items WHERE idOrdenes = $id_eliminar LIMIT 1";
                        $res1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql3);
                        if($res1 > 0) {
                            echo "<script>
                            location.href='index.php';
                            </script>";
                        } else {
                            echo "nada";
                        } 
     } 
     $isbn = $row['libro'];
     $cantidadOrdenes = $row['cantidad'];
     $usuario = $row['usuario'];
     $precio = $row['precio'];
     ?>
</form>
```

**Boton Confirmar Compra**

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div class="totalProd">
    <center>
      <h3>TOTAL: $
        <?php
                     echo $total; 
      ?>
      </h3>
    </center>
    <input type="submit" name="comprar" value="CONFIRMAR COMPRA">
  </div>
</form>
<?php if($_POST['comprar']) {
     
     $fecha = date('l jS \of F Y');
     $sql4 = "INSERT INTO lecturas_db.ordenes(isbn,cantidadOrdenes,usuario,precio,fecha) VALUES('$isbn','$cantidadOrdenes','$usuario','$precio','$fecha')";
     $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql4);
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: contestado en el post original https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218855/guardar-pedidos-en-base-de-datos/218882#comment407257_218882

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Guardar pedidos en base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218855/guardar-pedidos-en-base-de-datos)